# integrating an external program

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

So I have been tasked with integrating a program called "lightSIDE" into a hadoop job, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to go about this.

So essentially, rather than a single JAR, lightSIDE comes as an entire directory, including xml files that are crucial to its running.

Up until now, the way the data scientists on my team have been using this program is by running a python script that actually runs an executable, but this seems extremely inefficient as it would be spinning up a new JVM every time it gets called. That being said, I have no idea how else to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your own MapReduce jobs then it is possible to include all the jar files as as libraries and xml files as resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers for the LightSide Researcher's Workbench. LightSide also includes a tiny PredictionServer class to handle predictions on new instances over HTTP - you can see it [here on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/lightsidelabs/lightside/src/6ccd43b16fd85a7e36940f3e376418a6bcd8d61b/src/edu/cmu/side/recipe/PredictionServer.java).

If you want to train new models instead, you could modify this server to do what you want, drawing clues from the side.recipe.Chef class.